# How to insert list values to a dictionary in Python?

Tags: python, dictionary

How can I insert multiple emailAddress fields to attendees list in dictionary? I have two list addresses, names. And I want to loop through these lists to generate this dict. F.E

```
addresses = ["test@test.test", "nana@nana.nana"]
names = ["test", "nana"]
```

Result should be like this:

```
{
    "subject": "Let's go for lunch",
    "body": {
        "contentType": "HTML",
        "content": "Does mid month work for you?"
    },
    "start": {
        "dateTime": "2020-02-10T12:00:00",
        "timeZone": "Pacific Standard Time"
    },
    "end": {
        "dateTime": "2020-02-10T14:00:00",
        "timeZone": "Pacific Standard Time"
    },
    "location": {
        "displayName": "Harry's Bar"
    },
    "attendees": [
        {
            "emailAddress": {
                "address": "test@test.test",
                "name": "test"
            },
            "type": "required"
        },
        {
            "emailAddress": {
                "address": "nana@nana.nana",
                "name": "nana"
            },
            "type": "required"
        }
    ],
    "isOnlineMeeting": true,
    "onlineMeetingProvider": "teamsForBusiness"
}
```

I have tried to loop through each list and create a string:

```
for a in addresses:
    for n in names:
        attendees_body +='{"emailAddress": {"address": "%s", "name": "%s"}, "type": "required"},' % (a,n)
```

Then I tried to add this string to a dictionary, and to use json.dumps(dictionary) to format json file (which I need). But then I got result which looks like this

```
{"subject": "subjectas", "start": {"dateTime": "2020-02-10T12:00:00", "timeZone": "Pacific Standard Time"}, "end": {"dateTime": "2020-02-10T14:00:00", "timeZone": "Pacific Standard Time"}, "location": {"displayName": "Harry's Bar"}, "attendees": ["{'emailAddress': {'address': 'sasi@sasi.xui', 'name': 'zdarovenko'}, 'type': 'required'},{'emailAddress': {'address': 'sasi@sasi.xui', 'name': 'kurwenko'}, 'type': 'required'},{'emailAddress': {'address': 'nana@sasi.xui', 'name': 'zdarovenko'}, 'type': 'required'},{'emailAddress': {'address': 'nana@sasi.xui', 'name': 'kurwenko'}, 'type': 'required'},"], "isOnlineMeeting": true, "onlineMeetingProvider": "teamsForBusiness"}
```

Where some values are in "" and some in '' ..

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I editted my question. @JohnnyJohnBoy

Comment: You gave the expected result but is there a dictionary that you're starting off with that we  could see?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not super clear what you are asking but in essence I think it's a question of two parts:

1. Iterate through two different lists together
2. Insert the items from these lists into an existing Python dictionary with an existing list

Assuming that's correct then you can simply use the append method on the dictionary's list.  The function you need to use to get the aggregated data from the two lists is resolved using [zip](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/zip) which takes iterables (a list in this case) then aggregates them in a tuple.

I should say that json is not required here, I just used it instead of pprint to get the formatting nice.

```
    import json
    from collections import defaultdict
    
    addresses = ["test@test.test", "nana@nana.nana"]
    names = ["test", "nana"]
    
    my_dictionary = {
        "subject": "Let's go for lunch",
        "body": {
            "contentType": "HTML",
            "content": "Does mid month work for you?"
        },
        "start": {
            "dateTime": "2020-02-10T12:00:00",
            "timeZone": "Pacific Standard Time"
        },
        "end": {
            "dateTime": "2020-02-10T14:00:00",
            "timeZone": "Pacific Standard Time"
        },
        "location": {
            "displayName": "Harry's Bar"
        },
        "attendees": [
    
        ],
        "isOnlineMeeting": True,
        "onlineMeetingProvider": "teamsForBusiness"
    }
    
    for a, n in zip(addresses, names):
        contact = {
                    "emailAddress":
                        {
                            "address": a,
                            "name": n
                        },
                    "type": "required"
                  }
        my_dictionary['attendees'].append(contact)
    
    print(json.dumps(my_dictionary, indent=4, default=str))
```

This would yield the following result:

```
 {
        "subject": "Let's go for lunch",
        "body": {
            "contentType": "HTML",
            "content": "Does mid month work for you?"
        },
        "start": {
            "dateTime": "2020-02-10T12:00:00",
            "timeZone": "Pacific Standard Time"
        },
        "end": {
            "dateTime": "2020-02-10T14:00:00",
            "timeZone": "Pacific Standard Time"
        },
        "location": {
            "displayName": "Harry's Bar"
        },
        "attendees": [
            {
                "emailAddress": {
                    "address": "test@test.test",
                    "name": "test"
                },
                "type": "required"
            },
            {
                "emailAddress": {
                    "address": "nana@nana.nana",
                    "name": "nana"
                },
                "type": "required"
            }
        ],
        "isOnlineMeeting": true,
        "onlineMeetingProvider": "teamsForBusiness"
    }
```